# Class/Activity instance passed as parameter is null when assigning it to a class-wide variable and using it

Tags: java, android

I'm having some trouble with figuring out why my class-wide variable is null when I assign it in the method that receives it. I've tried reading other questions with regards to difference between references to variables, objects and so on but I can't really wrap my head around it and figure it out.

```
public class Class1 {
  private TestActivity testActivity;

  // This line of code is ran when an event is triggered:
  // But  testActivity seems  to be null and I get
  // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  //Attempt to invoke virtual method on this line:
  testActivity.getBackData(var);

  public void setParam(TestActivity testA){
    // Running testA.getBackData(var) here works fine.  
    // But assigning this.testActivty makes testActivity 
    //null outside of this method.
    this.testActivity = testA;
  } 
}
```

The activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate...{
    Class1  c = new Class1();

    c.setParam(TestActivity.this);
  }

  public String getDataBack(String str){}

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the method of TestActivity with:

```
public class Class1 {
  private TestActivity testActivity;

  // calling the method
  testActivity.getBackData(var);

}
```

which is a logic error.

You can only call the specific method of a class inside your method like this:

```
public class Class1 {
  private TestActivity testActivity;

  public void setParam(TestActivity testA){
    this.testActivity = testA;

    // calling the method
    testActivity.getBackData(var);
  } 
}
```

Your following comment:

```
  // This line of code is ran when an event is triggered:
  // But  testActivity seems  to be null and I get
  // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  //Attempt to invoke virtual method on this line:
   testActivity.getBackData(var);
```

is not how the Java works.

Comment: Thank you,  appreciate  it!